# Why is my query ignoring one of the WHERE clauses?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Morning,

I cant work out why my query (below) is ignoring the `WHERE` clause for the amzLive. And is still returning duplicates.

```
SELECT  asin
FROM    dbo.aboProducts
WHERE  (asin NOT IN
             (SELECT DISTINCT productAsin
              FROM   dbo.LowestPrices
              WHERE (priceDate > GETDATE() - 1))) AND (amzLive = 'true')
```

It is returning a list of items, but still bringing back the ones where amzLive is set to true or false.

Can someone see where I am going wrong?

**Update**
DB structure as requested...
aboProducts Table

```
id          int            Unchecked
asin        nvarchar(50)   Checked
codeType    int            Checked
sku         nvarchar(50)   Unchecked
amzPrice    decimal(18, 2) Checked
amzLive     bit            Checked
lastUpdated datetime       Checked
```

LowestPrices Table

```
id           int            Unchecked
productAsin  nvarchar(50)   Unchecked
price        decimal(18, 2) Unchecked
postage      decimal(18, 2) Checked
priceDate    datetime       Unchecked
twAmzPrice   decimal(18, 2) Checked
```

Comment: Morning where i am lol, well mid-morning :) yay! only an hour til lunch time!

Comment: What type of a column is `amzLive`? Did you try running the subquery by itself to see if the results are what you expect?

Comment: @thatuxguy Can you please show your data structure table?

Comment: Is there an `amzLive` column in both tables? Because this query is using the `aboProducts.amzLive` column.

Comment: Update made for the DB structure. there is only 1 amzlive col in the aboProducts table.

Comment: Have you tried removing the brackets?

Comment: no, it only seems to be the not in bit thats causing an issue. If i run it just on the aboProducts table i get the results i want. But I need to see if its in the `LowestPrices` table too

Comment: Post some sample data from both tables and the expected results. Otherwise, everyone is just guessing.

Comment: @podiluska is in `aboProducts`

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: @podiluska your solution worked a treat, with a one line removed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use 'true' and 'false' with bits, use a 1 or 0
2. A `left join` will make your query clearer and more predictable
3. FYI, SQL Server has money datatypes

eg

```
select ASIN
from aboProducts
    left join lowestprices
        on aboProducts.asin = lowestprices.productAsin
        and lowestprices.pricedate > (GETDATE()-1)
where lowestprices.productAsin is null
and aboProducts.amzlive=1
```

Comment: @thatuxguy Which line did you remove?

Comment: looking at it again, and copied the results into excel, its still brings back duplicates asins

Comment: @thatuxguy Add a distinct to the query if you need distinct values.

Comment: yeah that worked, thanks, now i just need to decide which answer to go with :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
Select *
From 
(SELECT  asin,amzLive
FROM    dbo.aboProducts
WHERE  (asin NOT IN
             (SELECT DISTINCT productAsin
              FROM   dbo.LowestPrices
              WHERE (priceDate > GETDATE() - 1)
              )
         ) 
       )X
where X.amzLive = 'true'
```

Also try this

```
SELECT ap.asin
FROM dbo.aboProducts ap
Left Join   (SELECT DISTINCT productAsin FROM dbo.LowestPrices  WHERE (priceDate > GETDATE() - 1))x
ON ap.asin  = x.productAsin
WHERE ap.amzLive = 'true' 
AND LEN(ap.asin) > 0 -- ap.asin IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  asin
FROM    dbo.aboProducts
WHERE  (asin NOT IN
             (SELECT DISTINCT productAsin
              FROM   dbo.LowestPrices
              WHERE (priceDate > dateadd(day,-1,GETDATE()) ))) AND (amzLive = 'true')
```